# User not available through input bindings on refresh Angular4

Tags: angular, nested, components

I have a Profile component that gets the User via an api call.

**ProfileComponent**

```
this.UserSubscription = this.auth.getUser().subscribe(res => {
 this.User = res;
})
```

and I pass the User data to the child

```
<section class="user-achievements" *ngIf="User">
    <achievements [User]="User"></achievements>
</section>
```

**AchievementsComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'achievements',
  template: `
        <ng-container *ngIf="User">
        <div *ngFor="let achievement of Achievements">
          <h5>Achievment</h5>
            <div>Name:</div>
            <div>Progress:</div>
        </div>
        </ng-container>`,
  styleUrls: ['./achievements.component.scss']
})
export class AchievementsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() User;
  Achievements;
  constructor(
    private api: ApiClient,
  ) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('this user', this.User);
    this.api.get(`users/${this.User.id}/achievements`)
      .subscribe( res => {
        this.Achievements = res.content;
      });
    }

  }
```

On reload the console shows my api call with undefined as the user. 
What is the correct way to load data into child components?

Answer (score 1):

His problem was `User` was an empty object so his condition was throwing a false positive.

Answer (score 0):

Give a type to User.

Some usefull code

```
@Input() user:string;
@Input() user:any;
@Inpuy() user: UserType

class UserType {
id:number
name:string;
}

constructor(user:UserType) {
this.user = user;
}
```